# Jquery animating banners

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to accomplish  creating an animated banner for my site. I created the images individually and was hoping that by using jQuery, I will be able to make the images flow into each portion of the table. Below is what I'm trying to accomplish. Too hard to describe so might as well draw it out.

[image]

Any help here will be greatly appreciated.

Oh, would be better if the table gets input via jQuery as well.

Following is my code:

HTML

```
      <div id="seller_banner">
      </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("div#seller_banner").html("<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
      $("div#seller_banner").delay(800).html("<table><tr><td class='moving banner'></td><td></td></tr><tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr></table>");
      $("div#seller_banner").find("table").fadeIn();
      $("#seller_banner").find("table td.moving").delay(2000).html("<img src='/seller/images/for_banners/lady_model_1.png'>");
      $("#seller_banner").find("table td.moving img").fadeIn();
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to give more detail. Maybe even attempt it yourself and come back when you get stuck? If you have made an attempt, show it!

Comment: Oops sorry. Forgotten the code after drawing. But anyways, I'm still onto jquery so might not be of much help anyways. This code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm still on to inserting the first banner in first. The ones later can be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

The GreenSock Animation Package is a pretty good alternative to JQuery for animation and if you've ever used it with Flash you'll be familiar with the syntax: http://www.greensock.com/

Comment: its in flash? Hmm. Don't think i would want that in my script unless its not doable in jquery.

Comment: No, it's not in flash. The person who created the package originally created it for flash but then re-wrote it for JS. There are a bunch of speed tests that shows of it's performance vs other JS animation packages as well.